# Sorting a 2D arraylist in Java with different lengths of 1D lists

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I have been trying to **lexicographically sort** a 2D `ArrayList` using a custom `Comparator`. But the lengths of every single 1D lists are different so I am not getting the expected result here is my code:

```java
List<ArrayList<Integer>> a = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
ArrayList<Integer> a1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> a2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> a3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> a4 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

a1.add(1);

a2.add(1);
a2.add(3);

a3.add(1);
a3.add(2);
a3.add(3);

a.add(a1);
a.add(a2);
a.add(a3);

Collections.sort(a, new Comparator<ArrayList<Integer>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(ArrayList<Integer> a, ArrayList<Integer> b) {
        if (a.get(0) < b.get(0))
            return 1;
        return -1;
    }
});
System.out.println(a);
```

So the input is `[[1], [1, 3], [1, 2, 3]]`

My output is `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3], [1]]`

The expected output is `[[1],[1,2,3],[1,3]]`

Please point out the errors and the additions required to make the code work

Comment: The JavaDoc of the compare method says: "Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second. - The implementor must ensure that sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x)) for all x and y. " <- You simply broke the contract of the compare method because you didn't even consider the case that both numbers could be equal (and return 0)

Comment: And you are only comparing the first numbers of your lists. You need to compare all numbers until you either reach the end of both lists or find an entry where they are not equal

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I want them to appear lexicographically but Im not able to do so

Comment: Does that mean I need to implement a **Comparator within a comparator** ?

Comment: No need to implement Comparator within a comparator. You just need a Comparator that actually does what you want and doesn't break the basic contracts of Comparator. You need to iterate over all elements of your lists and return 1, 0 or -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First determine which of the lists to be compared is the shorter one. You can determine this for example using the method `Math.min(int a, int b)`. Then compare each element of the first list with the corresponding element of the second list. If they are **not** equal, return the result of this comparison. If all are equal, compare the length of the lists and return this value.

```
List<List<Integer>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> listOne = new ArrayList<>();
listOne.add(1);

List<Integer> listTwo = new ArrayList<>();
listTwo.add(1);
listTwo.add(2);
listTwo.add(3);

List<Integer> listThree = new ArrayList<>();
listThree.add(1);
listThree.add(3);

listOfLists.add(listOne);
listOfLists.add(listTwo);
listOfLists.add(listThree);
    
Collections.sort(listOfLists, new Comparator<List<Integer>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(List<Integer> first, List<Integer> second) {
        int comp = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < Math.min(first.size(), second.size()); i++){
            comp = Integer.compare(first.get(i), second.get(i));
            if(comp != 0){
                return comp;
            }
         }
         return Integer.compare(first.size(), second.size());
    }
});
System.out.println(listOfLists);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to define a custom `Comparator` sorting your 2d integer `ArrayList` comparing the two `String` representations of two 1d  `ArrayList`: for example with `ArrayList` `[1]` and  `[1, 3]` you will compare the strings `"1"` and `"13"`. This can be obtained using the streams and `String.valueOf` methods like below , I assume you have no empty integer `ArrayList`:

```
Collections.sort(a, new Comparator<List<Integer>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) {
        String j1 = a.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(""));
        String j2 = b.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(""));

        return j1.compareTo(j2);
    }
});
```

This will produce your expected ordered output.

Comment: I would not omit the separator. Because for example the lists `[12, 20]` and `[1,220]` are considered equal.

Comment: @Eritrean, this is a good point, surely OP was talking about lexicographical ordering, but probably some example with edge cases would have helped.

Comment: I know it could be done like that but then again I didn't want to convert them to string and then sort

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need lexicographical ordering. Guava library has utility method which could help you:

```java
import com.google.common.collect.Comparators;
...
Collections.sort(a, Comparators.lexicographical(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
```